# KnockoutJS - show loading and no data messages

Tags: knockout.js

I'm using KnockoutJS and loading my view model via ajax. Before the load completes, I'd like to show a "Loading..." message, and if no data is loaded, I'd like to show a "No results." message. My initial attempt looks like this:

```
<ul data-bind="template: { name: 'mentions-template', foreach: mentions.data }">
    <li data-bind="visible: mentions.loaded() && mentions.data().length < 1">No mentions</li>
    <li data-bind="visible: !mentions.loaded()">Loading...</li>
</ul>


<script type="text/javascript">

    var viewModel = {
        mentions: {
            loaded: ko.observable(false),
            data: ko.observableArray()
        }
    }

    function loadData() {
       $.post(action, function(result) {
           viewModel.mentions.data = ko.mapping.fromJS(result);
           viewModel.mentions.loaded(true);
           ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
       });   
    } 

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    loadData();    
</script>
```

I expected that the first `li` element would only show if `viewModel.mentions.loaded` was false and `viewModel.mentions.data` contained some items, and that the second `li` would show up until `viewModel.mentions.loaded` had been set to false, but both items are displayed at all times. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've had problems using `!` in knockout bindings, have you tried `== false` instead?

Comment: Just did, same result. It's like knockoutjs doesn't even touch the existing `li` elements when it does the binding.

Comment: Odd. Because I've had similar issues, I typically add a `status` property to my view model and bind it to a `<span>` in the ui; the actual message is determined in a `ko.computable`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you have these static items inside of the `ul` your list, they don't actually get bound, as Knockout just processes each item in the array.

One way to achieve what you want, would be to do:

```
<ul>
    <!-- ko template: { name: 'mentions-template', foreach: mentions.data } -->
    <!-- /ko -->
    <li data-bind="visible: mentions.loaded() && mentions.data().length < 1">No mentions</li>
    <li data-bind="visible: !mentions.loaded()">Loading...</li>
</ul>
```

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/gw7bM/

Comment: Yeah I figured that would be the best way, and have started down that path, but for whatever reason, KO isn't updating the bindings when I populate the data array. I'm doing `ko.mapping.fromJS(result, viewModel.mentions.data);` and nothing happens.

Comment: I updated the fiddle.  If `mentions.data` has not been initialized by the mapping plugin, then you need to call it like `ko.mapping.fromJS(result, {}, viewModel.mentions.data);`

Comment: So I found I was using the wrong fromJS syntax. I changed it to use `ko.mapping.fromJS(result, {}, viewModel.mentions.data);` and everything works as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I've had similar issues with unexpected behavior when using the `visible` binding, try something like this:

```
var ViewModel = {
  mentions: {
    loaded: ko.observable(),
    data: ko.observableArray(),
    status: ko.computed(function () {
      if (loaded() && data().length < 1)
        return 'No Mentions';

      else
        return 'Loading...';
    });
}
```

Update your view with a `<span>`:

```
<span data-bind="text: status, visible: loaded"></span>
```